# How to declare a function outside of the class?

Tags: c++, cuda

Here is the scenario:

I have some class functions that have to be compiled by some C++-derived compiler (CUDA nvcc). However, I need the class declaration to be compiled by regular C++ compiler. I know that a class function has to be declared inside the class declaration. Not sure how to bypass this problem. Thanks!

Say I have a file "a.cpp":

```
class A
{
  private:
    int i;
  public:
    __global__ int f() {return i;}
}
```

Here `__global__` implies a CUDA kernel code that needs to be compiled by its specific compiler. However, I need "a.cpp" be compiled by regular C++ compiler.

I thought about using a wrapper that link against a kernel library built by CUDA compiler. However, the kernel need to reference the class private variable ("int i"), and I am trying to avoid passing them around.

Comment: The member function has to be declared inside the class body, but it can be defined elsewhere.

Comment: Can you post an example of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Actually, on a second read of your question, I'm no longer sure what you're asking.  Please can you clarify?  (i.e. edit your question to post an example)

Comment: This question is moot - `__global__` functions cannot be part of a class. Quoting from the documentation "Static member functions cannot be `__global__` functions."

Comment: @talonmies `f()` is not static

Comment: The question does not make sense to me either.  `__global__` functions must be of void type and cannot return a value.  Furthermore, if an object of the class is instantiated in host code, the `__global__` function, executing on the device, is not allowed to reference `i` (which is resident on the host) in any way, unless it is passed as a parameter (in some fashion).  All of these problems can be sorted out, however, with an appropriate wrapper function, if `i` is "passed around".  The question and code as written are not sensible to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a macro defenition:

```
#ifdef __CUDACC__
#define GLOBAL_CUDA __global__
#else
#define GLOBAL_CUDA
#endif
```

So when the CUDA compiler, gets the file it will see `__global__` if it is a normal C++ compiler it will just see a blank space

```
class A
{
  private:
    int i;
  public:
    GLOBAL_CUDA int f() {return i;}
}
```

Comment: It's a useful idea, perhaps, but the code as written by the original poster does not make sense, and is not valid.  Thus your code is not valid either.

Answer (score 3):

Implement the class member function as a wrapper of an `extern` function. You can then implement and compile the external function however you like.

In code:

```
extern "C"{
... quux(...);
}

class Foo{
public:
 ... bar(...){ return quux(...); }
}
```